# Java: Cannot find symbol variable

Tags: java, android

This is a copy/paste assignment for my class, but I am encountering this 'error: cannot find symbol variable total_pizzas' regardless of what I try. I have attempted to Invalidate and Restart, clean project, and even deleted the .iml files and .idea folder. I don't know what else to do at this point.

I have also tried renaming the variable in question to match, but it still throws that error regardless. I want to also add that this is in Android Studio.

The code is below (XML added):

this is the line I am having issues with:

```java
String totalText = getString(R.string.total_pizzas);
```

```
package com.example.pizzaparty;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNumAttendEditText;
    private TextView mNumPizzasTextView;
    private RadioGroup mHowHungryRadioGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Assign the widgets to fields
        mNumAttendEditText = findViewById(R.id.attendEditText);
        mNumPizzasTextView = findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
        mHowHungryRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.hungryRadioGroup);
    }

    public void calculateClick(View view) {

        // Get how many are attending the party
        int numAttend;
        try {
            String numAttendStr = mNumAttendEditText.getText().toString();
            numAttend = Integer.parseInt(numAttendStr);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            numAttend = 0;
        }

        // Get hunger level selection
        int checkedId = mHowHungryRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        PizzaCalculator.HungerLevel hungerLevel = PizzaCalculator.HungerLevel.RAVENOUS;
        if (checkedId == R.id.lightRadioButton) {
            hungerLevel = PizzaCalculator.HungerLevel.LIGHT;
        }
        else if (checkedId == R.id.mediumRadioButton) {
            hungerLevel = PizzaCalculator.HungerLevel.MEDIUM;
        }

        // Show the number of pizzas needed
        PizzaCalculator calc = new PizzaCalculator(numAttend, hungerLevel);
        int totalPizzas = calc.totalPizzas();
        String totalText = getString(R.string.total_pizzas);
        mNumPizzasTextView.setText(totalText + " " + totalPizzas);
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.pizzaparty.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number of people?"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="5"
        android:id="@+id/attendEditText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="How hungry?"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/hungryRadioGroup">
        <RadioButton
            android:text="Light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lightRadioButton" />
        <RadioButton
            android:text="Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/mediumRadioButton" />
        <RadioButton
            android:text="Ravenous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ravenousRadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
        android:text="Total pizzas: ?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calcButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="calculateClick" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the output from Android Studio that it provides when I hit the run button? If so, that is literally the only thing I get. If not, then I don't appear to know what you are asking for.

Comment: @Ferillius - Mario is wrong.  There will be no stacktrace.  For a *compilation error*.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the XML file.  Check that the definitions for "total_string" match up.  The names are case sensitive.  If you can't see the problem, add the XML file to your Question.

Comment: Also ... should `R.string.total_pizzas` be `R.id.total_pizzas`

Comment: @ Stephen, I added the XML file.

Comment: @Ferillius check strings.xml have you declared total_pizzas string there or not?

Comment: @AsadMukhtar No, the only thing in strings.xml is 

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">pizzaparty</string>
</resources>

Comment: @AsadMukhtar Added it to strings.xml and that fixed the problem. Thank you for your help. I guess the "guide" I'm supposed to be following omits steps or expects you to know this.

Comment: Declare total_pizzas string in strings.xml @Ferillius

Comment: Please attach the string.xml resource file.

Comment: You haven't declared string like this total_pizzas in your string file

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely not added the string "total_pizzas" to the res/values/string.xml file.

Open res/values/string.xml file and make sure it looks as following.

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">YOUR APP NAME</string>

    <string name="total_pizzas">YOUR OWN TEXT</string>
</resources>
```

app_name is most likely already declared and the only part you need to add is

```xml
<string name="total_pizzas">YOUR OWN TEXT</string>
```

YOUR OWN TEXT you will need to change to whatever you want.